# Get access to QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase methods and attributes from within QgsProcessingAlgorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I was wondering if there is a *simple* method to have access to methods and attributes of the `QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase` class **from within** a Processing script.

I can do it from *outside*, creating the dialog with the `createAlgorithmDialog` method:

```
dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
    "native:saveselectedfeatures",
)
```

But is it possible to do it within the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` script itself?

```
class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    
    ....
```

Why? An example could be to have access to the [messageBar](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.html#qgis.gui.QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.messageBar) object of the UI and add there a message when needed.

Trying what @J.Monticolo suggested, for instance, adding the following into the `processAlgorithm` method is not doing anything:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    self.dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog("my_provider:my_algorithm")

    self.dialog.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that")
```

Comment: Why do you want to access that message bar? Are you aware of the available methods to update the message bar?

Comment: yes I know that I can access the `iface` message bar from the main QGIS interface, but I'm trying to access the message bar (just to make an example) from the algorithm itself

Comment: You can't access the QGIS Interface (GUI) inside a processing algorithm because it's not thread safe and Qt crash when the GUI is modified from an other thread.

Comment: Exactly! Therefore I'm trying to access the objects of the UI of the algorithm, like the message bar

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it works.

I just added a method `display_dlg` :

```py
def display_dlg(self):
    self.dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog(
        "native:saveselectedfeatures",
    )
    self.dialog.show()
```

and after, in `initAlgorithm` :

```py
self.display_dlg()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a starting point :) If I'm directly adding `self.dialog = processing.createAlgorithmDialog("my_provider:my_algorithm")` in the `initAlgorithm` method I get a `RecursionError`. What I'm trying to do, for example, is to have access the the messageBar of the UI (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.html#qgis.gui.QgsProcessingAlgorithmDialogBase.messageBar). Let me also specify this in the question